# SQL. How to manage operator GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Can I have an influence on what I get in a result of the operator GROUP BY? That is exactly what would remove from result of the query and what to leave. For example, after I applied the JOIN to the two tables, I get the following result:

[image: first screen]

Now, after I append to my query

```
... GROUP BY firstname
```

I get the following:

[image: first screen]

But why is it removed in the second row? Why not remove the first row?

Can I influence by some way on it, if I use GROUP BY?

---

Queries (transcribed from the comments):

```
SELECT p.id, p.firstname, a.auto
  FROM persons AS p INNER JOIN auto AS a ON p.id = a.person_id

SELECT p.id, p.firstname, a.auto
  FROM persons AS p INNER JOIN auto AS a ON p.id = a.person_id
 GROUP BY p.firstname
```

How to write the query correctly?

I tried to use the ORDER BY for solution my question. But GROUP BY must always come before the ORDER BY. Therefore, in this situation, it cannot help me .

Comment: Can you post what database system you're using and the full query?

Comment: Relational databases don't really have a concept of "first row" unless you specify an "ORDER BY" clause the RDBMS will deliver the data in whatever order it encounters it. For columns that are not specifically grouped you get a random selection unless you apply a MAX, MIN or similar function.

Comment: It will be MySQL, and there will be non-aggregate columns in the select-list that are not cited in the GROUP BY clause, leading to semi-indeterminate behaviour such as arbitrarily dropping either BMW or Audi.  According to standard SQL, the query is malformed.

Comment: Before anyone can help you, you need to specify what result you actually want from your query.  For example, with the 4 row data set in the example data in my answer, which `id` value do you want to appear next to Alex's name?  And which vehicle type do you want to appear?  How is that made deterministic?  Indeed, why are you using GROUP BY?  You should use GROUP BY to control the scope of aggregate operators, such as COUNT or SUM or MAX or MIN.  You have no aggregates, so there is no obvious reason to use GROUP BY.

Comment: @JamesAnderson: A relational database language would have no use for `ORDER BY` syntax because relations have no ordering by definition. Please do not use the word 'relation' (or its derivatives) when you mean SQL. Note standard SQL has a [`FIRST_VALUE()` window function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018(v=sql.110).aspx), which FWIW will be in SQL Server 2012 and, as you point out, requires `ORDER BY` (though doesn't require that that the `ORDER BY` yields an unambiguous ordering).

Answer (score 2):

You must be using MySQL.

Your first query must be similar to:

```
SELECT id, firstname, auto
  FROM AnonymousTable;
```

Your second query is then similar to:

```
SELECT id, firstname, auto
  FROM AnonymousTable
 GROUP BY firstname;        -- Non-standard; MySQL only
```

In Standard SQL, if you have a GROUP BY clause, all non-aggregate values in the select-list must be listed in the GROUP BY clause (so the second query is malformed in Standard SQL).  Only MySQL allows you to leave non-aggregate values in the select-list out of the GROUP BY clause.

It is largely arbitrary which values are chosen when you use this feature.  For some (like the `id` column) the result is deterministic because all rows in the group have the same value of `id` for the given `firstname` (in the sample data).  For others (like the `auto` column), the value chosen is arbitrary.

If you had data like:

```
id    firstname     auto
1     Alex          BMW
1     Alex          Audi
2     Jakob         Opel
3     Alex          Honda
```

it would no longer be deterministic which value would show in the `id` column for the name `Alex` (it could be 1 or 3), and the model of the car is still indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

group by is an aggregate function (e.g. count of rows that match the group by) - so you "lose rows".

This site may help you : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

perhaps you mean to order by that row?